# Angular5's (click) event doesn't work in IE9 & IE10

Tags: angular5

In my angular5 app I created a link using anchor tag and calling a function in its  click event,it's working all browsers except IE9 & IE10.can anyone know why event handlers not working in IE9 & IE10?

**html code**

```
                <ul class="menu l-container brand-nav">
                    <li class="brand-nav__item parentMenuLi" *ngFor="let menu of menuObj;let i=index">
                        <a id="hd_{{menu.id}}" (click)="routeGoTo(menu)"  class="brand-nav__link" tabindex="{{i+2}}" title="{{menu.name}}" >
                            <span class="link-wrapper" [innerHtml]="menu.name"></span>
                        </a>                
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

**component**

```
 routeGoTo(menu){ 
    console.log('menu',menu);
    this.router.navigate([menu.url]);
  }
```

Comment: `onclick` attribute is supported by all the popular web browsers, including all versions of Internet Explorer, Please share your code

Comment: I edited my question with the code

Comment: try including `href` attribute in anchor tag